# Listener instantiated multiple times

Tags: google-chrome-extension, listener

I'm developing a Chrome extension in which I have a popup that calls the "begin" function of background.js. Background.js opens tabs and I have a listener in background.js that sends a message to the content_script.js of the tabs:

background.js

```
function begin() {
  var mySendedTabs = new Array();
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
  {             
   if(mySendedTabs.indexOf(tabId) == -1) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete")
    {
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { question: "What's your location ?" });
     mySendedTabs.push(tabId);                      
    }
   }                
 });
}
```

content_script.js replies with another message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request.question == "What's your location ?") {
   alert("Got a location request");
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({myLocation : location.href});
  }
});
```

There is no problem when I refresh my extension from the "chrome://extensions/" window. The problem is that if I run my program a second time (from the popup), the alert in content_script.js is fired 2 times. If I run my program again, the alert is fired 3 times... and so on.

It seen to me that the Listeners are still in memory although background.js is refreshed when I launch the program from popup, and that the Listeners are duplicated.

If I call

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(arguments.callee)
```

, all Listeners are removed and the program doesn't work anymore, even if I run the program again from popup.

I just want to get a clean browser window when I launch the program from popup.

I think I have to launch the listeners from the content scripts, that will not solve the problem but I don't know how to make singletons from my Listeners.

Comment: "`although background.js is refreshed when I launch the program from popup`" -- I don't understand what you mean. Why do you say your background page is "refreshed"? The state of your background page is persistent (unless you restart Chrome or update your extension); that's the entire point of a background page.

Comment: I think background page is refreshed because it don't remember my variable values from one run to another, the listeners are. I put `"persistent" : false` in my manifest.json but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Each time the popup is shown, your begin method is run, which in turn adds another listener, so it is normal that you end-up with an increasing number of listeners.
What you need to do is move the code that adds a listener outside the `begin()` method. The listener should be added once, when the background page is loaded.
Then you should also place `mySendedTabs` outside the `begin()` method (so the listener has access aways access to it).

I am not sure I understand what you mean by "I just want to get a clean browser window when I launch the program from popup.", but (if my guess is right) all you need to do inside the `begin()` method is re-initialize the `mySendedTabs` variables.

Your background.js could look like this:

```
var mySendedTabs = new Array();
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {             
    if (mySendedTabs.indexOf(tabId) == -1) {
        if(changeInfo.status == "complete") {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { question: "What's your location ?" });
            mySendedTabs.push(tabId);
        }
    }
});

function begin() {
    mySendedTabs = new Array();
}
```

(I assume the variable `mySendedTabs` is populated with tabIDs upon the creation of the tabs (by means of a callback).)

**UPDATE**:
BTW, it is a good idea to turn your background page into an event page. (In yur case it could only entail adding `persistent: false` in your manifest.)
Take a look at the **[docuemntation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)** for more info and instructions.